# Exception: In BootstrapHook.php line 32, how can I consistently resolve this?

Tags: composer-php, drupal-8, drush

My build process is (mostly working), but sometimes when I swap out to a new project, I am winding up with an error which looks like the output below.  I have found this error message extremely unhelpful in sorting out what my underlying issue might be.  And having resolved this issue in the past, and folded it into my build process, does not seem to have resolved it for all future builds of similar projects.  I am seeking advice on how to proceed here, would appreciate any help I can get, please.  Thanks.

-- Hugh Esco

```
# sudo -u jenkins /usr/local/drush/drush site-install \
    -y -vvv \
    --db-url='mysql://my_project_code_db_user_dev:a_somewhat_secret_db_password@localhost/my_project_code_db_dev' \
    --db-su=root --db-su-pw='my_very_secret_root_password' \
    --account-mail=site-admin@example.org \
    --account-name=admin \
    --account-pass=reallysecret \
    --site-name=efc9c26-00497.dev.my_project_code.example.org

 [preflight] Config paths: /opt/local/my_project_code/drupal/vendor/drush/drush/drush.yml,/opt/local/my_project_code/drupal/drush/drush.yml
 [preflight] Alias paths: /opt/local/my_project_code/drupal/web/drush/sites,/opt/local/my_project_code/drupal/drush/sites
 [preflight] Commandfile search paths: /opt/local/my_project_code/drupal/vendor/drush/drush/src,/opt/local/my_project_code/drupal/drush
 [bootstrap] Starting bootstrap to root [0.12 sec, 8.69 MB]

In BootstrapHook.php line 32:

  [Exception]
  Bootstrap failed. Run your command with -vvv for more information.


Exception trace:
  at /opt/local/my_project_code/drupal/vendor/drush/drush/src/Boot/BootstrapHook.php:32

 Drush\Boot\BootstrapHook->initialize() at /opt/local/my_project_code/drupal/vendor/consolidation/annotated-command/src/Hooks/Dispatchers/InitializeHookDispatcher.php:34

 Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\Hooks\Dispatchers\InitializeHookDispatcher->callInitializeHook() at /opt/local/my_project_code/drupal/vendor/consolidation/annotated-command/src/Hooks/Dispatchers/InitializeHookDispatcher.php:27

 Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\Hooks\Dispatchers\InitializeHookDispatcher->initialize() at /opt/local/my_project_code/drupal/vendor/consolidation/annotated-command/src/CommandProcessor.php:145

 Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\CommandProcessor->initializeHook() at /opt/local/my_project_code/drupal/vendor/consolidation/annotated-command/src/AnnotatedCommand.php:289

 Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\AnnotatedCommand->initialize() at /opt/local/my_project_code/drupal/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:221

 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /opt/local/my_project_code/drupal/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:1005

 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /opt/local/my_project_code/drupal/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:255

 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /opt/local/my_project_code/drupal/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:148

 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /opt/local/my_project_code/drupal/vendor/drush/drush/src/Runtime/Runtime.php:118

 Drush\Runtime\Runtime->doRun() at /opt/local/my_project_code/drupal/vendor/drush/drush/src/Runtime/Runtime.php:49

 Drush\Runtime\Runtime->run() at /opt/local/my_project_code/drupal/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php:72

 require() at /opt/local/my_project_code/drupal/vendor/drush/drush/drush:4

site:install [--db-url DB-URL] [--db-prefix DB-PREFIX] 
[--db-su DB-SU] [--db-su-pw DB-SU-PW] 
[--account-name [ACCOUNT-NAME]] [--account-mail [ACCOUNT-MAIL]] 
[--site-mail [SITE-MAIL]] [--account-pass ACCOUNT-PASS] 
[--locale [LOCALE]] [--site-name [SITE-NAME]] 
[--site-pass SITE-PASS] [--sites-subdir SITES-SUBDIR] 
[--config-dir CONFIG-DIR] [--existing-config] [-h|--help] 
[-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] 
[--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-d|--debug] 
[-y|--yes] [--no] 
[--remote-host REMOTE-HOST] [--remote-user REMOTE-USER] 
[-r|--root ROOT] [-l|--uri URI] [--simulate] [--pipe] 
[-D|--define DEFINE] [--notify] [--xh-link XH-LINK] 
[--druplicon] [--] <command> [<profile>]...
```

Comment: Please add all information about your question here instead of linking to external ressources

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been cross posted on [Drupal Answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/295448/15055).